# Github, node.js and grunt

Tags: node.js, github, gruntjs

I have downloaded a project from [github](https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template). In the installation manual, it says that **node.js** and **grunt** is required. [image] I have downloaded and installed node.js. I have also installed github for windows. But can not understand how do the rest of things. Would you help me how to use github project locally?

Comment: Are you familiar with using Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) or PowerShell? The lines in the quote are commands, which are often signified by a `$` prefix. Under the "tools" menu, GitHub for Windows should have an "open a shell here" option to get you up to the 2nd command.

Comment: There is no option "open a shell here". Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The open a shell option is located here: [image]

I would also recommend reading up on the basics of the command prompt  like http://dosprompt.info/ , and if you still need help leave another comment.